# Spring Integration Jms InboundGateway replyChannel Not Responding

Tags: spring-integration

This is an observation we have seen while using `replyChannel("letFrameworkCreateChannel")` auto create `replyChannel` via the framework as against `replyChannel(constructDirectChannel())`. In the former the consumer did NOT get the response and there were NO errors in the application. This happened to us in more than one application on **Kubernetes & Linux environment**, whereas we did NOT face this in **Windows**. We had to switch from `replyChannel("letFrameworkCreateChannel")` to `replyChannel(constructDirectChannel())` for the request-reply pattern to work. Kindly suggest why is the behavior with `replyChannel("letFrameworkCreateChannel")`

Comment: Show, please, the code which may let us to determine the problem. The simple project to run on our side would be great to reproduce. In general you don't need that `replyChannel()`. See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway-default-reply-channel. The `replyChannel` header populated by the gateway is enough to make request-reply pattern to work.

Comment: Thanks Artem, we couldn't reproduce the problem in Windows, shall try our best to share you one. The reason we used `replyChannel1()` was to reply to the `JmsGateway' from an errorflow / thread switch. Read the docs, we don't need it there either, as our reply is always for/consumed by the `gateway` only